# Trim Multiple Paragaraph php

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to trim the paragraph content with 100 characters. But I am not able to do for multiple paragraph.

for example

```
    <div class="div-1">
     <div class="section-1">
       <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
      </div>
      <div class="section-2">
         <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."</p>
         <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,"</p>
       </div>
</div>
```

I want to trim the second paragraph with 92 character along with ellipses.

Please guide me, how to sort out this issue?

Comment: You can simply use "substr(_display_string($row->article_details),0,100)" , and the next one from 101 to 200

Comment: Is *ellipses* another word for dot or punctuation? Meaning you want to split the string at new sentence but max 100 characters?

Comment: how are you getting the paragraph content? from database?

Comment: Yeah getting from database @davithuroyan

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you one solution you can use not `strip_tags` instead of `trim`.

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);  // the output will be text without tags 
//Test paragraph. Comment Other text
```

In your example how I see you should keep the `div` tags. So you can write

```
strip_tags($text,'<div>')
```

The  strip_tags($text) without any tag as a second param remove all tags  from text;
The referer is

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Solution 2

```
$html = preg_replace('#\<p>[{\w},\s\d"]+\</p>#', "", $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for display to a user, you can [use css](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/).

It won't truncate to a certain character length, instead you can choose a length of the containing element. It only works on a single line of text though (a major drawback).

For anything more complicated, see [this article](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/). It has an example of doing it in PHP like you asked.